# How to mark as read Facebook message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to mark Facebook page conversation message as read using GraphAPI ?
I can't figure out the correct POST

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations

Comment: But what do I post, I tried adding read to tags and that didn't work. What am I missing ?

Comment: Who said something about post? (Well you did, but I didn’t.) To get a message marked as “read” – how bout _reading_ that message …?

Comment: Using the API to get the conversations and messages did not mark them as read, that's why I asked this question